# Is there an equivalent construct for SPPersistedObject that can be used in SharePoint Online (e. g. provider-hosted add-in)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, configuration

I'm developing a SharePoint app. There is a requirement to move away from using lists to store configuration data. When comparing SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2013, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent construct to SPPersistedObject.  Is this correct?  If so, what are alternative solutions in SharePoint Online to store   configuration data that can be persisted and accessed by a SharePoint add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property bag associated with several types in the Client Object Model. These values get persisted in the content database.

[Web.AllProperties property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.allproperties.aspx)